# IIS Web App Deploy in Azure Devops does not transform web.config correctly for .netcore project

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, deployment, azure-devops

I have defined a release in AzureDevops to deploy my aspnet core app to on-premise IIS server. It copies all files successfully, but the can not transform the webconfig file correctly. However when I publish the app using VS webdeploy with same web.release.config, it transforms the web.config correctly.

I have checked the checkbox of "XML transformation" and "XML variable substitution" under "File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options".

The final web.config produced by azuredevops deployment, has duplicate xml elements for the ones that I used "xdt:Transform=Insert" and also it lacks the xml element for "environmentVariable".

Here is the transform file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <modules xdt:Transform="Insert" runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>
      <aspNetCore>
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
      <staticContent xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <mimeMap fileExtension="mp3" mimeType="..." />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

And here is the result web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\app.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
                <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
            </modules>
            <staticContent>
                <mimeMap fileExtension="mp3" mimeType="..." />
            </staticContent>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
                <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
            </modules>
            <staticContent>
                <mimeMap fileExtension="mp3" mimeType="" />
            </staticContent>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

My azure-pipelines.yml is as follow :

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with your yaml pipeline. When i checked the build log of Vsbuild task, i found the web.config was automatically created and applied the transformation. When i downloaded the build artifacts and checked the web.config file, the file was correctly transformed. No duplication elements and  No missing element.

[image]

The duplicate xml elements you encountered is because if the `XML transformation` is enabled in release pipeline, the web.config that has been transformed by Vsbuild task will be transformed again, which caused the duplication. ()

The possible fix is to disable the `XML transformation` of your release pipeline, since the transformation was done by vsbuild task.

Or you can add a flag `/p:IsTransformWebConfigDisabled=true` to msbuild arguments to prevent Vsbuild task from transforming web.config file in build pipeline. Then you can enable `XML transformation` in the release pipeline.

Comment: So why it works fine with WebDeploy Publish in Visual studio and it does not work in AZureDevops ? Also consider that I do not have web.config in my aspnet core project and it only created when it is published.

Comment: What is the build task you used to build your app in your build pipeline? And what is its configuration?

Comment: I shared azure-pipelines.yml

Comment: I tested with your yaml, When Vsbuild task build the solution, it automatically generated a web.config and be transformed correctly against the transform file web.release.config. You donot need to check the checkbox of "XML transformation" in your release pipeline. I updated above answer.

Comment: Everything is fine, just environmentVariables is missing now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `web.PROFILENAME.config` file is set to `Content`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35466754/16940